# Twitter Send Direct Message C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I am using the following code to send out message to one of my other ids. Can someone please explain what am I missing here. Both accounts are followers to each other and the option is also enabled to receive direct messages from everyone.

```
private static void sendMessage(string message)
{
    //The facebook json url to update the status
    string facebookURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json?user_id=1699575980&screen_name=MuneebZulfee&text=some message";

    //set the access tokens (REQUIRED)
    string oauth_consumer_key = "**************************";
    string oauth_consumer_secret = "***************************";
    string oauth_token = "******************************";
    string oauth_token_secret = "*****************************";

    // set the oauth version and signature method
    string oauth_version = "1.0";
    string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

    // create unique request details
    string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
    System.TimeSpan timeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
    string oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

    // create oauth signature
    string baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" + "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&screen_name={6}&text={7}&user_id={8}";

    string baseString = string.Format(
        baseFormat,
        oauth_consumer_key,
        oauth_nonce,
        oauth_signature_method,
        oauth_timestamp, oauth_token,
        oauth_version,
        Uri.EscapeDataString("MuneebZulfee"),
        Uri.EscapeDataString("some message"),
        Uri.EscapeDataString("1699575980")
    );

    string oauth_signature = null;
    using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret))))
    {
        oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("POST&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(facebookURL) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString))));
    }

    // create the request header
    string authorizationFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", " + "oauth_signature=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\", " + "oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\", oauth_token=\"{5}\", " + "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

    string authorizationHeader = string.Format(
        authorizationFormat,
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
    );

    HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(facebookURL);
    objHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
    objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    using (Stream objStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString("user_id=1699575980&screen_name=MuneebZulfee&text=some message"));
        objStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    }

    var responseResult = "";
    try
    {
        //success posting
        WebResponse objWebResponse = objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(objWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
        responseResult = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw exception error
        responseResult = "Twitter Post Error: " + ex.Message.ToString() + ", authHeader: " + authorizationHeader;
    }
}
```

Comment: what goes wrong? do you get an error message from twitter, or is an exception thrown?

Comment: Have you used Fiddler or some other tool to see what's actually going out over the wire? Have you compared that with what goes out over the wire when you perform that function with a working Twitter client?

Comment: Yes its all the same. But still the issue. You can try it if you want to. The account is mine and I wouldnt bother getting any debugging messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Tweet Sharp

```
var twitterApp = new TwitterService("******************", "****************");
twitterApp.AuthenticateWith("**********-*********************", "****************");
twitterApp.SendDirectMessage(new SendDirectMessageOptions() { ScreenName = "username", Text = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString() });
```

This does for me

Comment: Just to let you know, TweetSharp is no longer maintained.

Comment: @Linvi are you sure about this? as twitter mentions this on their website as recommended library

Comment: Yes I am sure of this. Twitter mention this as a recommended library because it used to be and unfortunately they do not remove deprectated libraries.